# Looping through folders and running code not always working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to loop through all the folders inside a directory and perform certain tasks. In this case the tasks are (i) refresh the active workbook and (ii) remove all workbook connections.

```
Sub LoopThroughFolders()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim FF As Scripting.Folder

Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set FF = FSO.GetFolder("C:\...\") 'Change directory as appropriate
PerformTasks FF

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub PerformTasks(FF As Scripting.Folder)

Dim F As Scripting.File
Dim SubF As Scripting.Folder
Dim WB As Workbook

For Each F In FF.Files
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(F.Path)

'CODE GOES HERE

WB.Close SaveChanges:=True
Debug.Print F.Name
Next F

For Each SubF In FF.SubFolders
PerformTasks SubF
Next SubF

End Sub
```

If I replace the appropriate line with

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

or equivalent procedure, all the workbooks in the root folder are refreshed as expected. However when I try the code

```
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count).Delete
Loop
```

to remove all the connections from the workbooks, the program goes over all the files, but nothing happens, i.e. the connections that were supposed to be deleted remain in the workbooks. Notably this code executes as expected if launched from the workbook itself, removing the connections in the calling workbook.

Why isn't the code for removing connections working when looping through the folders? Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `activeworkbook` if you set `wb`?

Comment: I think I know what it is. Let's say .Count returns 2 connections. .Items has those connections in .items(0) and .Items(1).

Just try switching to **ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count - 1).Delete**

If this works, give me a shout, I'll post it as an answer. I don't have Excel here to try it myself

Comment: @CyberClaw that makes sense if only the last connection remained but OP seems to say none are removed?

Comment: Nope, he is always removing the "count connection". Problem is, count goes from 1 to X (0 meaning none), and Items go from 0 to X-1 (because 0 is already a position)

Comment: @findwindow - it's just an example. You're right.

Comment: Oh. In that case, `Connections.Count - 1` is still only deleting one. Seems like you need an increment in your loop.

Comment: Wait, what am I right about? The `wb` or the last connection?

Comment: @CyberClaw I get a Subscript Out of Range error.

Comment: @Miguel cyberclaw is on the right track, you need an increment in your loop.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw other people using the cycle like you did online, so I was wrong.